# SQL Server 'Real Time' Mirroring Possible?

Tags: backup, sql-server-2005, synchronization

We have a SQL Server that has important databases for our clients, if the server goes down we want another server to be ready to be switched over (we would just change the IP). The question is, how can we automatically sync the primary SQL Server to the secondary one periodically through out the day? Or even in real time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do database mirroring/log shipping : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187016.aspx.  Here's an article by Paul Randal you might want to look at as well : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee523927.aspx.  That guy knows his stuff.

Answer (score -1):

I am in the proccess of doing the same thing.

I am going with this method:
[Peer-to-Peer Transactional Replication MSSQL 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152536.aspx)

Here is the article for your version of MSSQL
[Peer-to-Peer Transactional Replication MSSQL 2005](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152536%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Not real time, sorry ;) Plus has demands on the database ;) Mirroring is a better solution for two point - faster, less load AND - no change in the database necessary.